# SSIS Fuzzy Lookup Transform not matching values with spaces in on and not in the other

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm working on an SSIS project to transfer data from a legacy system to a new system. This is the first time I've used SSIS but so far all has gone well, until now.

I have to match product names from the old and new system. Some are clean matches and a standard lookup catches those. Some are not and I'm using a fuzzy lookup on the no match output of the main lookup to try and catch those afterwards. This works on some thing but what seems like the most obvious matches it completely misses. for example

```
Source data: FG 45J
Target data: FG45J
```

This is not matched by the fuzzy lookup. I've tried ticking and unticking the spaces delimiter box to no avail. The threshold is set to zero so everything gets through but similarity and confidence are zero on the relevant output records. Some others do return non zero similarity etc but they don't have spaces. Matches to return is set to one although I've tried setting this up to four to see if this made any difference and it didn't. I expect I've missed something but I can't work out what.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: My gut instinct is that the FG is too short of a ... can't recall the term but in some of the string matching algorithms they break words up into smaller chunks and if enough chunks match, odds are good the two words match. It may be that `ABCFG 45J` would match `ABCFG45J` because the minimum word length was met. I think in our internal implementations 3 was the minimum length. That said, don't be afraid to clean your source data before feeding it into the fuzzy lookup. If the space is causing you trouble, rip it out ~ `REPLACE([Col1], " ", "")`

Comment: thanks billinkc. That's exactly what I did. I just ripped out the spaces. i just hope it doesn't come along and bite me in the a** later.